# Stuck in a loop when there is no matching - Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, matching

So here I am stuck with my program where its a simple thing to do. so basically in the search metod is where I have 3 variables as you can see, Char P char T and List pos. Below the method you can see there is a Main where its says what value the char P, char T has and my idea was to make a matching program where I enter a value P and looks if there is a same value in char T. Ones it founds out, it should continue until the value is done. so in the main method after it found out the result, it should give you the index of what position the value is set to.

Now to the problem is, if I give a correct value example P =abc T = abcqweqweabc it would give me a correct, but if I do abcqweqweqwe it will loop all the time and never end which is killing my processor and ram (hehe) and I have been trying to figure out but I can't find the problem. It seems like it should work and I don't understand why it does like it.

```
public class StringSearch {
    public static void search(char[] P, char[] T, List<Integer> pos) {
        int i = 0;
        int j;
        while(i!=P.length){ 
            for (j= 0; j<T.length; j++){ 
                if(P[i] == T[j]) { 
                    i++;
                    if(i == P.length) { 
                        pos.add((j-(P.length-1)));
                        i = 0; 
                        if(j==T.length-1) { 
                            i = P.length;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> where = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        search("abcx".toCharArray(), "abcdabcxxabctx".toCharArray(), where);
        for (int i : where) {
            System.out.println(i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Also please! If you need to know something. Just comment and I will probably answer you in a minute! Feel free to ask question aswell!

EDIT: To give a exactly meaning of what I'm trying to do is that, Our Char T is where the "text" is and char P is where letters are that I want to match P and T. So whenever we find a correct matching between char P and T it should be add in the list which we called pos. which will give us later a result where in the index the matching is the same. like T = qweabcqwe and P = abc. It should give us a result of 4. so what I'm trying to do is to see if there is a matching between those two and where in the position are they the same and if there is, put in the list and then the loop at the main method will tell us where.

EDIT PART 2.3:

```
public static void search(char[] P, char[] T, List<Integer> pos) {

            for (int i=0;i<=T.length-P.length;) { 
                if (T[i] == P[0]) {
                    boolean match=true;
                    for (int j=0;j<P.length;j++) {
                        if (T[i+j] != P[j]) {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (match) {
                        pos.add(i);
                        i = P.length -1;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Integer> where = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            search("abcx".toCharArray(), "abcdabcxxabctx".toCharArray(), where);
            for (int i : where) {
                System.out.println(i); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over P, you should iterate over T IMO. Anyway, I think your problem can be solved if you take the 'if(j == T.length-1)' to to the inner for()-loop's scope. Because you have no means of breaking out when the end of T is reached, but i != P.length

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you break it down more clearly?

Comment: I will do that Tim B! Give me few minutes please :)

Comment: @TimB I hope its more clear now! If not. Write ones again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is even one case where

```
if(P[i] != T[j])
```

then you set i to 0

```
else {
  i = 0;
```

and you get stuck in the while loop

BUT basicaly what you are trying to do is something that gives you the same result as indexOf()

Try this :

```
String Str = new String("qweabcqwe");
String SubStr1 = new String("abc");

System.out.println( Str.indexOf( SubStr1 )); // will print 3
```

Comment: Hmmm. So I tried it and it gave me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.  where I removed the else function and added instead `if(P[i] != T[j]) { i = 0`. Am I right?

Comment: sorry was not finished.

Comment: Oh yeah. I could do that aswell but I tried to learn the "harder" way which is by KMP algorithm, Maybe a bit complicated but for me its a stupider thing when we have as you said, the indexOf but I think this is more for udnerstanding the alghorithm..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the KMP algorithm explaind in detail using Java here to give you some hints if you want to implement it yourself: http://tekmarathon.com/2013/05/14/algorithm-to-find-substring-in-a-string-kmp-algorithm/

Comment: Been reading all about it and I can't go any further. I came so far as I have in my post and the only problem I see is the last loop. where it makes it loops all over again.

Answer (score 0):

To find the index of every character that is the same at the same position in each array just do:

```
for (int i=0;i<P.length && i<T.length;i++) {
   if (P[i] == T[i]) {
       pos.add(i);
   }
}
```

You only need one loop as you are only comparing one value.

If you want to find the location of the substring then you do need a nested loop but it can still be a simple for loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<=P.length-T.length;i++) { // Can stop when we get to within T length of the end of P
   if (P[i] == T[0]) {
       boolean match=true;
       for (j=0;j<T.length;j++) {
          if (P[i+j] != T[j]) {
             match = false;
             break;
          }
       }
       if (match) {
           pos.add(i);
           // You might want to add T.length-1 to i here to cause it to skip, it depends if you want to find overlapping results or not. (i.e. searching for bobob in bobobob.
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: hmm, So I tried to do as you said but It doesn't give any results when running it. so whats happend is its looping over and over again. I think the for loop is wrong since our T is our "long text" and P is out "short text" so I should be T-P if im correct? anyways, I tried both but did not give me any results aswell ...

Comment: Yes if T is the longer text you need the variables the other way around everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, did you mean like change the values from T to P and P to T?

Comment: I also found a problem. Because your for-loop is not having an added i++ which could give it a problem because if the i doesnt add up, it will loop at the same thing. Am I right?

Comment: Actually it was invalid code and wouldn't compile, you are right. I missed the i++ out and it should be there. I've added it to my example now.

Comment: Oh okey, So I will try to figure out somewhere from there I guess :)